# Shiny App in R: How to connect input and output

Tags: r, shinyapps

- I do not know how to connect input (n) in the slider and output (plot). When I move the bottom on the slider in the shinny app, the plot did not change. I am wondering if the output and input did not link together approporatedly.

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(shiny)

  plot<-function(x,y,xlim=c(-3,3)){
  x <- seq(-4, 4, by=0.01)
  norm_dens <- dnorm(x)
  t_dens <- dt(x, df = n-1)
  df = data.frame(x = x, z = norm_dens, t = t_dens)
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x)) +
     geom_line(aes(y = z, colour = "z"))+
     geom_line(aes(y = t,color = "t"))+
    labs(x="x", y = "")+
    scale_color_manual(name = "l", values = c("z" = "blue", "t" = "red"))+
    coord_cartesian(xlim = xlim)
  }
  plot(x,y)
  ## UI function
  ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId="plot")),
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             "Sample Size",
             sliderInput("n", label = "n", value = 5, min = 2, max = 100),step=1)
      )
  )
  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output) {
     reactive({
        df %>%
          filter(n %in% input$n)
      })
    output$plot<-renderPlot({

      plot(x,y)
    })
  }

  ## Run shiny app
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the reactive here. Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

plot<-function(x,y,xlim=c(-3,3),n){
    x <- seq(-4, 4, by=0.01)
    norm_dens <- dnorm(x)
    t_dens <- dt(x, df = n-1)
    df = data.frame(x = x, z = norm_dens, t = t_dens)
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x)) +
        geom_line(aes(y = z, colour = "z"))+
        geom_line(aes(y = t,color = "t"))+
        labs(x="x", y = "")+
        scale_color_manual(name = "l", values = c("z" = "blue", "t" = "red"))+
        coord_cartesian(xlim = xlim)
}

## UI function
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput(outputId="plot")),
    fluidRow(
        column(2,
               "Sample Size",
               sliderInput("n", label = "n", value = 5, min = 2, max = 100),step=1)
    )
)
# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot<-renderPlot({
        req(input$n)
        plot(x,y,n=input$n)
    })
}

## Run shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)`enter code here`
```